# how to write a code for collision of two bitmaps

Tags: android, android-activity, bitmap

I tried to develop a game apps which having a ball bitmap and square bitmap. Square bitmap is scrolling from down to up and the ball is fall from up to down.

I want to write a code to collision of two bitmaps( ball and square)

any one can help me pls..

```
private void doDraw(Canvas c) {
/*  int width = c.getWidth();
    int height = c.getHeight();
    c.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, backgroundPaint); */


     Bitmap ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ball); //Load a ball image.
     ballH=ball.getHeight();
      ballW=ball.getWidth();
     Bitmap kangoo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.b);
  sh=kangoo.getHeight();

      sw=(kangoo.getWidth());
      ballX = (int) (mScrWidth /2) - (ballW / 2) ; //Centre ball X into the centre of the screen.
        ballY = -50; //Centre ball height above the screen.
 c.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
```

c.drawBitmap(kangoo,-10, vall--, null);
 c.drawBitmap(kangoo, (sw), vall--, null);

```
    synchronized (model.LOCK) {
        ballX = model.ballPixelX;
        ballY = model.ballPixelY;


    }

    //c.drawBitmap(ball, ballX,ballY, ballPaint);
     c.drawBitmap(kangoo,-10, vall2--, null);
     c.drawBitmap(kangoo,(sw), vall2--, null);
     c.drawBitmap(kangoo,-10, vall3--, null);
     c.drawBitmap(kangoo, (sw), vall3--, null);
```

}

This is my code..
Everything is run perfectly except collision ..
The two objects are crossing only..